# Basis for the intersection of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V=\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and $a=(1,1,2)$, $b = (0,1,3)$, $c=(2,4,5)$ and $d=(-1,0,-1)$ be the elements of $V.$ Find a basis for the intersection of the           subspace spanned by $\{a,b\}$ and $\{c,d\}$ and also find its dimension.

What I have done it till now is row reduced to echelon form but how do I proceed further?

Comment: Find the solutions of: $\alpha a+\beta b=\gamma c+\delta d.$ Note that you are looking for no more then $2$ vectors.

Comment: You say you have "done it till reduced echelon form" but what is "it"?  What matrix?  And why did you make that choice?  These are relevant to understanding the solution.

Comment: matrix of (a,b)= row1 -->(1,0,1) and row 2 --> (0,1,3/4).        and matrix of (c,d) = row1--> (1,0,-1) and row 2---> (0,1,3)

Comment: OK, so why do you think it's useful to form those matrices and row-reduce?

Answer (score 1):

As Itay says, you are looking for linear combinations of the form 
$$
    \alpha a + \beta b = \gamma c + \delta d \iff \alpha a  + \beta b - \gamma c - \delta d = 0
$$
Let $A$ be the matrix whose *columns* are $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$.  Then a quadruple $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta)$ as above gives rise to a vector $x = (\alpha,\beta,-\gamma,-\delta)$ in the nullspace of $A$.  For this reason, we seek the RREF of $A$:
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 2 & -1 \\
    1 & 1 & 4 & 0 \\
    2 & 3 & 5 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\longrightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & -9/5 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1/5 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 2/5
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
Let $R$ be the matrix on the right-hand side above.  Since $A$ and $R$ are row-equivalent, any relations among the columns of $R$ also hold among the columns of $A$, and vice-versa.  Since evidently:
\begin{gather}
     r_4 = -\frac{9}{5}r_1 + \frac{1}{5} r_2 + \frac{2}{5}r_3\\
\iff
     5r_4 = -9r_1 + r_2 + 2r_3\\
\iff
    -9r_1 + r_2 = -2r_3 + 5 r_4
\end{gather}
we must have
$$
     -9a+b = -2c +5d
$$
Indeed, both the left- and right-hand sides evaluate to $(-9,-8,-15)$.  This is one nonzero vector in the intersection of the span of $\left\{a,b\right\}$ and the span of $\left\{c,d\right\}$.  I'll leave it to you to show that this is the only (independent) one.  So the intersection is spanned by this vector.

Comment: its dimension will be 1?

Comment: @KkumarTanwar: Its dimension is either 1 or 2.  What would it mean if the dimension were 2?